# Add directory to the end of the list of include search paths for compile_commands.json in ccls

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include, intellisense

I have a simple C project with an `includes` folder that contains my header files. To get ccls to look into the header files in that folder, I added this into my VS Code's `settings.json` -- `"ccls.clang.extraArgs": ["-Iinclude"],`. However, I want this setting to be specific to my project. I checked the ccls wiki and saw that I could do that with `compile_commands.json` or `.ccls`, but I don't know how to go about it. It also doesn't have an example for the former.